# Is there a direct way to obtain the RE for the handle-finding DFA of a grammar?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, compilers, parsers, lr-k

[LR parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) for a (CFG) grammar uses a handle-find automaton (which is a DFA) to find the handles. Such automata can be constructed by computing the [canonical collection of sets of LR(0)/LR(1) items](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_LR_parser).

Is there a way to obtain the [RE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) of the handle-find automaton, *directly* from the given grammar?

---

Example: Below are the grammar for balanced parentheses and its handle-finding DFA (from the [book: Engineering a Compiler](https://www.elsevier.com/books/engineering-a-compiler/cooper/978-0-12-088478-0)).

[image: balance-grammar]

[image: handle-finding-dfa]